# Auto increment column from DB in ListView

Tags: sql, sql-server, listview, auto-increment

My goal is to be able to automatically increment the Id Column when I insert a record into the Db in ListView.

For example,

```
DB Table
ID     Name
1      Test1
2      Test2
```

In the ListView InsertItemTemplate

```
Insert   ID: 3    Name:(User enters in a name)
```

Is there a way to handle this on the Visual Studio side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the column `ID` as `IDENTITY(1,1)`

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name>
( 
  ID    INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  Name  VARCHAR(100)
)
```

If you add the `Name`, the ID value automatically inserted.

If you want to manually insert next ID, **find the Maximum ID value** like the following and pass it to `INSERT` statement.

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) + 1 AS ID FROM <table_name>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the column properties in the DB? I only want to change things on the software side

Comment: Yes... You can find the MAX(ID) + 1 and pass that value to DB.